# Sejda-Console HTML to PDF Conversion

Tags: bash, sejda

I am attempting to convert HTML documents to PDF format using a bash script.  I've found that the Sejda converter does a good job of fully rendering the charts I need, but am having some trouble using it in the console rather than the web interface.  Although the documentation at https://www.sejda.com/developers gives an example of how to convert a URL, does anyone know of a similar way to convert a local file in the console?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML to PDF conversion is not available via the sejda-console.

However, you can convert a local file through the sejda.com API, not only URLs, by posting the file's HTML contents.

Here's an example converting HTML code from the command line:

```
curl -i https://api.sejda.com/v1/tasks\
 --fail --silent --show-error \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data '{"htmlCode": "<strong>HTML<\/strong> code here",
       "type": "htmlToPdf" }' > converted.pdf
```

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't use Sejda using the windows command console currently?